# very large static table with no Where clause

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I have a 200 million record static demographics table with 230 columns.  There are no indexes nor are there any unique individual columns. 
This table has `ZIP (varchar(5))` and `STREET NUMBER (varchar(10))` columns, which will be used in practically all joins to this table.

There will **never** be a Where clause as this table is used as a 'matching' platform against a single client table.  The client table can be anywhere from 20K to 3 million rows, and will have a ZIP and Street number column as well.  So at a minimum my joins will include: `ZIP = ZIP` AND `STREET_NO = STREET_NO`. There will be other join conditions as well, but they will use functions and such for fuzzy matching.  The `SELECT` clause will be dynamic and will include any number of columns, so a covering index doesn't seem practical.

I am at liberty to add indexes on the massive table.  So far I added ID identity primary key, to give me a Clustered Index.  Then I added a non-clustered index on (ZIP, STREET NO).

However, I am not sure that the Clustered index on a surrogate key is necessary since this is static data.

Would I possibly be better off making the Clustered Index on (ZIP, STREET NO), since there will never be a Where clause and this is a JOIN issue?  I am seeing a lot of bookmark look-ups on the current clustered ID  column (taking up 80% of the execution time in the execution plan) whenever I run a query and thought this might be suspicious.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Before you make any decision about whether you should have a clustered or non-clustered index, test all the possible types of queries that will access the table. You'll probably also want to consider building indexes on your foreign key columns and the columns used for search arguments and for grouping and sorting. When testing possible indexes, make sure to include all your data-modification operations. 
 So run you query and let the SQL Server Optimizer do it's job ! he will tell you what you need to do(where to create your index and what type) to make your query faster.